# Kotlin: changes made in super constructor are overwritten

Tags: kotlin

I am having trouble understanding what Kotlin is actually doing:

My unit test looks like this:

```
@Test
fun testReadCursorRequest() {
    val xml = fromFile()
    val parser: ReadCursorRequestParser = ReadCursorRequestParser(xml)
    assertEquals(0, parser.status)
    assertEquals(134, parser.contacts!!.size)
}
```

My parser looks like this

```
abstract class EnvelopeParser(val xml: String) {
    abstract fun parseResponse(response: Element)

    init {
        parseResponse(xmlFromString(xml))
    }

    // non-related stuff
}
```

```
class ReadCursorRequestParser(xml: String) : EnvelopeParser(xml) {

    var contacts: List<AddressBookElementParser> = mutableListOf()     

    override fun parseResponse(response: Element) {
        // here some parsing stuff, fills the contacts-list
        println("size is: ${contacts.size}")
    }
}
```

println says `size is: 134`, the unit test says: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <134>, actual <0>`.

Why?

Comment: Inside the parsing stuff, is there a local variable named `contacts`? If there is, then its size is printed, not the size of the `contacts` stored in the property.

Comment: Also, your test doesn't seem to call `parseResponse()`. Where is it (or should it be) called?

Comment: I am sorry if this was unclear due to the stuff I just skipped from this entry here, I wanted to keep things as short and context-relevant as possible. 
EnvelopeParser is in fact calling parseResponse from its constructor. 

In fact, I run this in debug mode with break points, so am 100 % sure there is no local variable contacts, IntelliJ renders the value of the contacts member when breaking at println.

Comment: `contacts` is not mutable. Why do you write `contacts!!`?

Comment: If contacts is not mutable, the developers of Kotlin should rename mutableListOf()

Comment: I think @voddan means not nullable. I don't see where you call parseResponse method in your test. You only create an object and your contact list is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said in comments, `parseResponse(...)` is called from inside the `EnvelopeParser` constructor.

Then what's happening when you create an instance of `ReadCursorRequestParser` is:

1. An object is allocated.
2. The `ReadCursorRequestParser` constructor is called, and it calls the superclass constructor straight away.
3. The super constructor (that of `EnvelopeParser`) invokes `parseResponse(...)` and thus assigns the `contacts` (and at this moment this is actually a non-empty list).
4. The super constructor then returns, and the constructor of `ReadCursorRequestParser` continues.
5. **The `ReadCursorRequestParser` constructor assigns `contacts` again, now it's an empty list**.

The reason for this is that each constructor first calls its super constructor (if any) and only then initializes the properties and executes the `init` blocks, and all the changes a superconstructor made to the state declared in the class (not the base classes) will be overwritten by the class' own constructor.

This simplified example shows this behavior: [(link)](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/rrdg9fn46rg3563uvigo8o2bp6/coclfe252ard8rc7s8g766f8j1).

---

The easiest workaround is to change the declaration of `contacts` to something like

```
lateinit var contacts: List<AddressBookElementParser>
```

With this declaration, the constructor won't reassign the `contacts`.

But I'd rather strongly recommend you to avoid calling `open` functions in a constructor because, if overridden, they might (and usually do) depend on the **derived class state, which has not been initialized** yet, and also the **changes they make will be overwritten** by the derived class constructor. You can even end up with some part of the changes persisted because they are done to the superclass state and the other part erased -- definitely not what you want to see in everyday life.